# leanModel ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi how i can render a different form using leanModel dialog box? Currently this is how the lean model works:

```
<a id="go" rel="privateMsg" name="signup" href="#signup">With Close Button</a>

<div id="signup" style="display: none; position: relative; opacity: 1; z-index: 11000; left: 50%; margin-left: -202px; top: 200px;">
            <div id="signup-ct">
                <div id="signup-header">
                    <h2>Create a new account</h2>
                    <p>It's simple, and free.</p>
                    <a class="modal_close" href="#"></a>
                </div>

                <form action="">

                  <div class="txt-fld">
                    <label for="">Username</label>
                    <input id="" class="" name="" type="text">

                  </div>
                  <div class="txt-fld">
                    <label for="">Email address</label>
                    <input id="" name="" type="text">
                  </div>
                  <div class="txt-fld">
                    <label for="">Password</label>
                    <input id="" name="" type="text">

                  </div>
                  <div class="btn-fld">
                    <a href="#" class="close">Cancel</a>
                  <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
                  </div>


                 </form>
            </div>
        </div>

$(function() {
    $('a[rel*=privateMsg]').leanModal({ top : 100, closeButton: ".modal_close,.close" });
});
```

The leanModel js is as follows :

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        leanModal:function(options){
            var defaults={top:100,overlay:0.5,closeButton:null};
            var overlay=$("<div id='lean_overlay'></div>");
            $("body").append(overlay);
            options=$.extend(defaults,options);
            return this.each(function(){
                var o=options;
                $(this).click(function(e){
                    var modal_id=$(this).attr("href");
                    $("#lean_overlay").click(function(){
                        close_modal(modal_id)
                    });
                    $(o.closeButton).click(function(){
                        close_modal(modal_id);
                    });
                    var modal_height=$(modal_id).outerHeight();
                    var modal_width=$(modal_id).outerWidth();

                    $("#lean_overlay").css({"display":"block",opacity:0});
                    $("#lean_overlay").fadeTo(200,o.overlay);
                    $(modal_id).css({"display":"block","position":"fixed","opacity":0,"z-index":11000,"left":50+"%","margin-left":-(modal_width/2)+"px","top":"100px"});
                    $(modal_id).fadeTo(200,1);e.preventDefault()
                });
            });
            function close_modal(modal_id){
                $("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200);$(modal_id).css({"display":"none"})
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

How i can improve this code so that i can open a dialog box just for any form? Also if i would like to load signup div from ajax how can i do so? Thanks

Comment: Can you create a demo in http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: render new form based on what event?

Comment: @charlietfl based on link. If it means form then form if it means info then info

Comment: are you stuck on using this modal? there are numerous others with much better API's and content flexibility

Comment: @charlietfl can give sample of them? Actually my idea is to use one for all purpose. When i click a link like javascript:sendMessage(user_id) i need to load a form for send message, if i click javascript:info(info) i need to load an info popup box.